# $http.delete returns error 404

Tags: angularjs, crud, http-delete

I am new to Angular and I'm trying to build a CRUD using the MEAN stack.

Yet I am having trouble with Angular to call the DELETE function on the server side.

Here is my Angular App.JS

```
var app = angular.module('topshelf', [])

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope','$http',
function($scope , $http){
  var Mydata = {};
  $http.get("http://localhost:8080/inventory").success(function(data,status,header,config){
    $scope.Mydata = data;
  });

  $scope.delete = function($index) {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/ingredients/" + $index;
    $http.delete(url).success(function(err,data){
        if (err){ console.log(err);}
        $scope.Mydata = data;
        console.log("test");

    });
  }
}]);
```

and here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>TopShelf</title>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app ="topshelf" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="top-navigation">
    <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Ingredient</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="ingredients in Mydata">
                <td>{{ingredients.name}} </td>
                <td>{{ingredients.quantity}} </td>
                <td>  Add / Edit / <a ng-click="delete($index)">Delete</a></form></td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Also, here is my server code specifying the routes though when I try the routes with POSTMAN it works fine.:

```
var express = require('express');
var Ingredients = require('./models/ingredients.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/labelleassiette');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/index.html");
})

app.get('/inventory',function(req,res){
    Ingredients.find(function(err,ingr){
        res.json(ingr);
    })
})

app.post('/add', function(req,res){
    var entry = new Ingredients({name: req.body.name, quantity: req.body.quantity});
    var self = this;
    Ingredients.find({name:req.body.name}, function(err,data){
        if(data.length){
            res.send(500,"Ingredient exists!");
        }
        else{
            entry.save(function(err){
                if (err) {console.log(err);}
                else { console.log('Saved to db')}
            });
        res.redirect('/');
        }
    })
})

app.put('/ingredients/:id',function(req,res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var obj = req.body;
    Ingredients.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {name: obj.name, quantity: obj.quantity}, function(err){
        if (err) {console.log(err);}
        console.log("updated");
    })
})

app.delete('/ingredients/:id',function(req,res){
    Ingredients.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id,function(err){
        if (err) {console.log(err);}
        console.log("effacé");
        res.redirect('/');
    })
})

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("listening on port 8080!");
});
```

i am getting a DELETE http://localhost:8080 404 not found on my browser's console.

Thank you guys for your help

Comment: I'd say your error is on the server side if you are getting 404s. Some server code would be nice.

Comment: Or you're not using the right URL. Using an index to identify a resource is not a good idea at all. A resource should have a unique, non-changing location. The resource at `/ingredients/3` shouldn't be "relocated" at `/ingredients/2` just because you deleted `/ingredients/0`. You should also use consistent URLs. Why do you get a list of ingredients at `/inventory`, and deleting from `/ingredients/xxx`? The list of ingredients should be at `/ingredients`.

Comment: @JohnF. I added some server side code. Although when I try my delete route with Postman it does work properly.

Comment: On your delete route why don't you send back a status code of 200 if successful?

Comment: why you do a lot res.redirect if something is working. Return a json for the add, return something if the delete is successfull but not redirect

Comment: On your delete route instead of res.redirect, use res.status(200).send ("it worked!");

Comment: Also, if it works on postman i would say that your best bet would be the network tab in your browser developer tools. I'm not sure if youre familiar with them already, but in Chrome you can see the exact URL and type of request that was fired to the server. I would double check to make sure it matches what you are sending in postman

Comment: You can also check which route is fired and giving 404 error in your  terminal or CMD where you are running your server.

Comment: @JohnF. Thanks for the tip. I changed res.redirect to res.status(200) and I don't get the 404 error no more. However when I refresh the home page the element is not deleted (and obviously it is still on the database).
I tried again on postman and it did erase it from the database. I think something is wrong with my Angular app.js